# How to clone TFS-2018 nuget feed?

Tags: tfs, nuget, nuget-server

I have local corporate TFS 2018 server and Nuget on it.
I create a nuget-feed. 
This feed i will use for 1 iteration.
Then, i need to create next feed,for next month. It is out buisness process.

So, how to clone nuget packages from old feed to new? Or, can i clone feeds?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to write some scripts using the REST APIs to accomplish it. There's no way to clone a feed at present.

I'd suggest **not** doing it and correcting your business process. There's no reason to do this. You can add tags to specific package versions to correspond to releases, if that's your ultimate goal.

Comment: Yes, i mean that we make release every month and i want that in old release source code programmer could not add new packages, but when new iteration starts - i will add new versions of packages to this branch.

Comment: @AdmiralLand No such a feature to clone a feed in TFS, you can try to create a new one, then write scripts to publish the same packages....